# Getting Login Faliure with error code 0

Tags: yodlee

I'm using Yodlee SOAP API endpoints and in my error logs I'm getting **Site Refresh Status** as **LOGIN_FAILURE** with error code 0 (which as I understand is **not an error** according to Yodlee docs). I was wondering what could be the cause of this? Is it an expected behavior? I'm assuming this is not a successful login.

Here is the returned xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
  <ns21:getSiteRefreshInfoResponse xmlns:ns21="http://refresh.refresh.core.soap.yodlee.com">
  <getSiteRefreshInfoReturn><siteRefreshStatus>LOGIN_FAILURE</siteRefreshStatus>
  <siteRefreshMode>NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE</siteRefreshMode>
  <code>0</code>
  </getSiteRefreshInfoReturn>
  </ns21:getSiteRefreshInfoResponse>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Yodlee Support and I got the answer that it is expected behaviour and users need to login again to get the instant refresh and refreshing sites should work again.